# How can I avoid Entity Framework Core OrderBy a list property from doing a Top (1) per list item in the database?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm making a query to the database using EF Core 2.0.1 and in particular, the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.1 NuGet package.

Here are my models:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(string value, Guid anotherId)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Value = value;
        AnotherId = anotherId;
    }

    protected Bar()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public Guid AnotherId { get; protected set; }
    public string Value { get; protected set; }
}
```

I create 10 `foo` instances, which have a list of 2 `bar` instances each and save that to the database.

When I try and order by the `Bar.Value` property where `AnotherId` equals `anotherId2`, it makes a total of 30 calls to the database.

Here is my setup and query to order by a value property on a bar instance where it has the anotherId2:

```
Guid anotherId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid anotherId2 = Guid.NewGuid();

using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
{
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("a", anotherId1), new Bar("z", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("b", anotherId1), new Bar("y", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("c", anotherId1), new Bar("x", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("d", anotherId1), new Bar("v", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("e", anotherId1), new Bar("w", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("f", anotherId1), new Bar("u", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("g", anotherId1), new Bar("t", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("h", anotherId1), new Bar("s", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("i", anotherId1), new Bar("r", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.Add(new Foo {Bars = new[] {new Bar("j", anotherId1), new Bar("q", anotherId2)}});
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

using (DbContext dbContext = GetDbContext())
{
    // By this point, only 7 calls are made to the database
    List<Foo> foos = await dbContext.Set<Foo>().Include(x => x.Bars)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Bars.First(y => y.AnotherId == anotherId2).Value)
        .ToListAsync();

    Assert.That(foos.First().Bars.Any(x => x.Value == "q"), Is.True);
}
```

When I use SQL Profiler it shows 30 SQL queries to the database!

[image: 30 SQL Calls]

There are 20 calls that look like the query below, one for each enumeration of anotherId2 and the bar instance:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [y0].[Value] FROM [Bar] AS [y0] WHERE ([y0].[AnotherId] = @__anotherId2_0) AND (@_outer_Id = [y0].[FooId])',N'@__anotherId2_0 uniqueidentifier,@_outer_Id uniqueidentifier',@__anotherId2_0='0AC1FBCA-6DEF-4F50-B4AA-CEC7286135B8',@_outer_Id='A6A1785A-B313-4EE7-A0B6-307F54D6F74A'
```

How can I stop it making these 20 calls to the database but still order `foo`'s by the value in the anotherId2 instance?

Comment: What would be your SQL equivalent of what you'd like to do?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

TLTR: Use `.ToList()`

So i've spent a few days looking into this issue and found this issue on github that documents similar behaviour to what I found
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10430

It suggests that there is a bug/problem with `.ToListAsync` which makes it order in memory.  The fix is to use `.ToList()` (synchronously) which generates only one query instead of the 20 calls I found.